# Extending Shopware customers API to include all customer's addresses

Tags: plugins, shopware

I am new with Shopware plugin development, please how to call all addresses related to a single customer?

Shopware v5.4.*

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question to show, what you have already tried and what is not working. Including source code can also help to unterstand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all addresses of a customer using the `AddressRepository`:

```php
// or you can inject the session and models services
$userId = $this->container->get('session')->get('sUserId');
$addressRepository = $this->container->get('models')->getRepository(Shopware\Models\Customer\Address::class);

$addresses = $addressRepository->findBy(['customer' => $userId]);
```

`$adresses` will be an array of `Address` objects.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer has inspired me to find what I was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

After some research and inspiration from [Paweł Napierała](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6192122/pawe%C5%82-napiera%C5%82a), I found what I was searching for, here is the final result:

```
public function getOne($id)
{
    $result = parent::getOne($id);
    $addresses = $this->getManager()
            ->getRepository(\Shopware\Models\Customer\Address::class)
            ->findBy(['customer'=>$id]);
    $resultArray = $this->getManager()->toArray($addresses);
    $result ['addresses'] = $resultArray;
    return $result;
}
```